# .fpk firmware unpacking

Tags: unpacking, firmware-analysis

I am working on firmware update file [`prod-build-Isat2-V02.00.03-DFU.fp2`](https://zippisat.com/IsatPhone2Upgrade/prod-build-Isat2-V02.00.01-DFU.fp2).
I extracted it and I've got some bin files. I analyzed these binary files with binwalk:

`binwalk -E RDA-533.bin`

The entropy of these bin files didn't give any information and when I opened these files with IDA, it didn't give subblocks and functions.
It seems these files are compressed or encrypted.
How can I analyze these bin files as efficiently as possible?

Answer (score -1):

You can find files File1.bin ... File6.bin in "C:\temp" directory after running IsatPhone 2 Firmware Upgrade Tool and selecting firmware. It does not need a connection to physical device, just firmware and tool.Unfortunately you can't decrypt these files in contrast to "IsatPhone Pro" model in which files were not encrypted.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I statistically analyzed extracted files, what are your reasons that file is encrypted? Because of entropy of extracted file, Doesn't it compressed or encrypted?

Comment: I can't share my report related to this research due to NDA. You can trust me or not, but I'm 100% sure this firmware is encrypted.

Comment: Thanks for helpful answer, but I'm studying on working encryption methods of firmware updates generally. Would it be possible if  you give me a sample of firmware with specific encryption method for my work?